# Query for dependencies

Tags: dependencies

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get -f install` in terminal to resolve unmet dependencies.

Comment: sorry this command is not working